# Returning data from or sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Am retrieving data from a database using json

CODE:

```
The values of ($id_from= 1 and  $id_to= 4)
```

The sql statement is

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM {$this->_table} WHERE comm ='$idfrom$idto' or comm ='$idto$idfrom'  ";
```

This returns no results

But when i do :

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM {$this->_table} WHERE comm =14 or comm =41  ";
```

It returns all results

My database
[image]

Where could i be making a mistake in the first sql statement

Comment: try to put like this $sql ="SELECT * FROM {$this->_table} WHERE comm =' ".$idfrom$idto." ' or comm =' ".$idto$idfrom." '  ";

Comment: First, output your query to see what it looks like. `echo $sql;` What type is the `comm` column?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yup your are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `comm` column is of INTEGER type use the following sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->_table} WHERE comm IN ($idfrom$idto, $idto$idfrom);";
```